# Flutter debugging: Setting debug boolean flags

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to debug an issue I was having and I've seen in [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13325) answer an advice to set `debugPrintScheduleBuildForStacks` to true.

I've managed to find the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/debugPrintScheduleBuildForStacks.html) for it however, nowhere on the internet I was able to find a guide on how to actually use them.

I've tried setting it as a global variable, a variable inside my widgets as well as changing it directly in the source file ([debug.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/debug.dart)) however, I did not manage to see the debug logging as in the answer mentioned above.

Can someone explain, or point me to some docs on how to use it?

Comment: just see the log output and check the difference when you set it to `true` or `false`

Comment: This question was *how* to set it to `true` or `false`?  
I've tried a few things as mentioned above but did not see any difference in log output.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Inside build() in main.dart

I have used debugPrintScheduleFrameStacks.

You can replace it with debugPrintScheduleBuildForStacks.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrintScheduleFrameStacks = true;
```

doc: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_for_web/latest/widgets/debugPrintScheduleBuildForStacks.html